# How to get each data from multiple tables in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have a multiple html tables in a same page, I want to get country code when on click on country get nearest country code value

Ex:- 1).country-click nearest -- India
Ex:- 2).country-click nearest -- China
Ex:- 3).country-click nearest -- Japan

Here is my table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="country">Country</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="code">India</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="country">Country</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="code">China</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="country">Country</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="code">Japan</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is script code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        console.log($(this).parents().closest('tr').find('#code').html());
    });
});
```

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: IDs need to be unique. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use siblings for table rows

Sorry for snippet code formating, I can't format it in this editor for some reason.

You are doing good on finding closest tr, now you have to check sibling rows that contain element with "#code" id (you should use class instead of id here, id must be unique, as berko commented).

Here is jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){             
        alert($(this).closest('tr').siblings().find('#code').html());
    });
});
```

..and here is snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){             alert($(this).closest('tr').siblings().find('#code').html());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="country">
  <tr>
    <td><button>Country</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="code">India</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id='country'>
  <tr>
    <td><button>Country</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="code">China</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<table  id="country">
  <tr>
    <td><button>Country</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="code">Japan</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```